# How to plot a corrugated circle in cartesian?

Tags: python, geometry, cartesian-coordinates

I'm looking for a way to plot a [corrugated circle](https://www.mypandakitchen.com/1656-large_default/emporte-pieces-rond-ondule.jpg) in Python.
[image: Corrugated circle]
My attempt doesn't produce the correct output:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import pi

x=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y=x

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

circle = (X-np.cos(2*pi*0.2*Y))**2 + (Y-np.sin(2*pi*0.2*X))**2 - 5.

plt.contour(X,Y,circle,[0])
plt.show()

theta = np.linspace(-pi,pi,100)
courbure = np.sin(theta*10)

plt.plot(theta,courbure)
plt.show()
    
circle2 = (X-(courbure*np.cos(theta)))**2 + (Y-np.sin(theta)*courbure)**2 - courbure**2
plt.contour(X,Y,circle2)
plt.show()
```

[image: Attempt at drawing a corrugated circle]

Thank you.

Comment: Try to detail a bit more your future questions. For instance, I think you have narrow down the problem yourself to the equation which is wrong. Mention it in your text and ask for the correct one. Moreover, adding an image in the core is fairly easy as you can simply copy/paste them, try it next time!

Answer (score 1):

I have plot a corrugate circle using a sinusoidal wave of a frequency egal to 10. The radius oscillate between 0.9 et 1. because i take the negative absolute part of the sinus. The amplitude is divided by 10.

For increase the corrugation you have to increase the frequency.
Here f=10.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import pi

x=np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
y=x

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

circle = (X)**2 + (Y)**2 - (1+ -np.abs(np.sin(np.arctan(Y/X)*10))/10)

plt.contour(X,Y,circle)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to detail your code + tips on how he can modify it towards his expected results. For instance, what is the influence of the different coefficient on the "wave"?