# How to plot a corrugate sphere in cartesian?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a corrugate sphere like golf balle.
I have succeeded to plot a corrugate circle with this code :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import pi

x=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y=x

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

circle = (X)**2 + (Y)**2 - (1+ -np.abs(np.sin(np.arctan(Y/X)*10))/10)

plt.contour(X,Y,circle)
plt.show()
```

Now I want the same idea but in 3D. So the goal is the plot a sphere in 3D with a radius function of a sinus in cartesian coordinate. How should I do this, and which MatPlotLib function should I use?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what equation you'd want to plot?

Comment: The only restriction is to have an equation describing this sphere in Cartesian coordinates. x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - R^2 with R=f(sinus)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Here is his 2D example from earlier today. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879754/how-to-plot-a-corrugated-circle-in-cartesian

Comment: What is `sinus` in `f(sinus)`? You're aware that one parameter is insufficient to describe a 2d object, right?

Comment: Yes sure, (X)**2 + (Y)**2 (Z)**2 - R^2 ; R = r0 + np.abs(np.sin(np.arctan(Y/X)*10))/10